# React stack html from json blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project and am trying to convert a blob of JSON into JSX markup.

I have this code working, but it only seems to render the very first item. I am unsure how to get it to return the required, entire stack.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-matsumoto-q8h0c?file=/src/Home.js

The JSON blob would look something like this:

```
{
    "hero": {
        "body": "cxbvcbvcbv",
        "title": "The idea2",
        "socials": {
            "youtube": "",
            "facebook": ""
        }
    },
    "founders": {
        "body": "zxczxczxczx",
        "title": "Founders1",
    }
}
```

The main function for retrieving the stacks looks like this:

```
getStacks() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.rawContent.content)) {
        return(
            <div key={key}>                    
                {this.stackBuilder(key, value)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the current result:

[image: Current result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `for` loop but are returning an element on the first iteration (line 130 in your sandbox). You probably want to [`map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) them instead.

```
getStacks() {
    return Object.entries(this.state.rawContent.content).map(([key, value]) => {
        return <div key={key}>{this.stackBuilder(key, value)}y</div>;
    });
}
```

Comment: but its not an array - just a stack of objects?

Comment: @TheOldCounty `Object.entries(...)` is transforming an object into an array of `[key, value]` tuples. Even though it's not an array per se, you need to treat it as such to map every element in the object's stack to an actual React/JSX component.